Strange issue with hammerspoon window movement
I am new to HS and I just try to implement a simple function to make my active window left half, here is my code, I'm confused as to why I have to press cmd+left three times to make this work?
hs.hotkey.bind({ "cmd" }, "left", function()
    local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
    local f = win:frame()
    local screen = win:screen()
    local max = screen:frame()
    f.x = max.x
    f.y = max.y
    f.w = max.w / 2
    f.h = max.h
    win:setFrame(f, 0)
end)

and here is what happened to my computer when i try this hotkey


The code works just fine for me; seems like the function isn't being called properly. For eg, win:setFrame(f, 0) 0 is animation duration, which should be instantaneous but yours is still animating. Maybe try adding logs to debug?

As an aside, do check https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.grid.html
